# Should I call my mom?

Tags: earthbound

Calling my dad lets me save my game and lets me know how much money is in my bank account.  Calling my mom didn't seem to do much of anything. Why should I bother calling her?

Comment: Even worse clickbaity title "Why should I bother calling my mom?"

Comment: I thought this was some 'kid with mom issues' question lol

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Ness can suffer from an ailment called [**Homesick**](http://earthbound.wikia.com/wiki/Homesick) by not talking to his mother for long periods of time. When he has this status condition he can sometimes miss turns in battle.

Calling your mother will prevent Ness from becoming homesick and it will also cure the homesick ailment! Silly moms.

Comment: Note that only calling works. I have visited Ness' mother while homesick and it does not cure it.

Comment: A Chick (hatched from a Fresh Egg) can also be Used to cure Homesickness.  This is less reliable though, as the Chick will turn into a Chicken over time.